# How to describe configuration of topic kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I want to describe the configuration of one topic. I developed a script using confluent-kafka-python librairie (version 1.5.0) and my version of python is 2.7.
My final goal is to be able to change the retention time to my topic (retention.ms), but for this I need to extract all configuration of my topic and change just what I want and leaving the others as they have been defined.

My script:

```
def describe_topic(admin_client, topic):

resources = [ConfigResource(confluent_kafka.admin.RESOURCE_TOPIC, topic)]
fs = admin_client.describe_configs(resources)
for resource, f in fs.items():
    remote_config = f.result()
    print(remote_config)
    return resource, remote_config
```

But I have this error :

> Error
> File "kafka.py", line 192, in describe_topic
> resources = [ConfigResource(confluent_kafka.admin.RESOURCE_TOPIC, topic)]
> File "environment/mamba-6Od8R-HF-py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/admin/config_resource.py", line 33, in **init**
> resource_type = ConfigResourceType[str(resource_type).upper()] # pylint: disable-msg=unsubscriptable-object
> File "/product/tedhdev/environment/mamba-6Od8R-HF-py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum/**init**.py", line 394, in **getitem**
> return cls.*member_map*[name]
> KeyError: '2'\

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I would suggest using python3

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, i can't use Python 3. It can't work with python 2?

Comment: I'm not sure. Python2 is end of life, though, so why cant you upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

```
import kafka
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, ConfigResource, ConfigResourceType

client_conn = kafka.KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092")
print(client_conn.describe_configs(config_resources=[ConfigResource(ConfigResourceType.TOPIC, "topic")]))
```